# Fedora 24: ports show as open when scanned from server, but closed when nmapped from outside

Tags: fedora, iptables, firewall, nmap

I have a Fedora 24 server, serving an Angular2 project. Angular2 automatically opens ports `3000` and `3001` once the service is started. However, although running `nmap localhost` shows the ports are open, when I run an nmap from a remote computer, these ports are showing as closed.

Is there an `iptables` setting I can use to open these ports publicly, perhaps? Or anything similar?

I tried running:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3001 -j ACCEPT
```

But this has not helped and the ports remain closed when scanned from outside, and I cannot view the served content (internal requests function fine).

Output of `netstat --an | egrep "3000|3001"`:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::3001                 :::*                    LISTEN`
```

A `curl` to the server's 'external' IP address works fine internally but won't work when run from other machines.

Comment: Please add to the post the output of `netstat -an | egrep "3000|3001"`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the solution was to run the following command:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=FedoraServer --add-port=3000/tcp
```

Seems that on Fedora 24, or the Fedora 24 as set up on linodes perhaps, iptables doesn't have a TCP entry.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the description, the problem seems to be that the server's firewall blocks incoming requests to the Angular development ports.  Firewall configurations can vary from fairly simple to incredibly complex, please be careful and make sure you understand what you are doing.

That being said, the most likely solution is to open the ports in your firewall, as you correctly hypothesized.  Both inbound and outbound traffic must be allowed through in order for a client to be able to use it. Outbound traffic is often unfiltered, so you can leave that as-is.  It might be enough to simply change `OUTPUT` to `INPUT` in your iptables-commands for things to work.

If that doesn't do it (or even better, before you try the above), take a look at the output of `iptables -nvL --line-numbers` and check for rules similar to the ones you are about to add.  Insert your rules right above or below as to minimize the risk of breaking anything.

Here is the output on one of the machines I work with to give an example of what I mean:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    5608K  815M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    3010K  621M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    68754 3002K DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
4    14095 1083K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
5     397K   21M TCP        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
6    45083 8704K UDP        udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
7     128K 6265K REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with tcp-reset
8    45085 8707K REJECT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
9        1    52 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4647K packets, 1421M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain TCP (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    56599 3172K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
2    54495 2814K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
3     158K 9164K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443

Chain UDP (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

This is still rather simple, but just appending new rules to the `INPUT` chain wouldn't help.  The rules similar to what you want are in the `TCP` chain, so we'd add the rules there:

```
iptables -A TCP -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

If all that still doesn't help, check if the external machine is using IPv6 to access the server and use `ip6tables` accordingly.

Comment: `iptables -A TCP -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT` results in `no chain/target/match by that name.`

Comment: @AmyTMcBride I think you mistook my example as the actual solution.  Either way, kudos for figuring it out yourself.